# trim trailing zeros not quite working

Tags: javascript

I have a number of prices on a page that arein 4 decimal places. Some products are priced in 4 decimal places, but some are only in 2.

At the moment our website is set to display in 4 decimal places for every product and I have to use javascript to trim down the prices on those products that aren't 2 decimal places.

So I have prices like so...

£0.1234

£1.1000

£10.9900

£100.0000

I have the following javascript which works fine for prices that have a number greater than 1 after the decimal point, but it fails on prices where there are just 0's after the decimal point...

```
$.each($("#mydiv"),function(){
  var price = $(this).text().replace("£","");
  var number = parseFloat(price);
  var integerPart = number.toString().split(".")[0] == 0 ? 0: number.toString().split(".")[0].length;
  var decimalPart = number.toString().split(".")[1].length;
  if(decimalPart > 2){
    $(this).text("£" + number.toPrecision(integerPart + decimalPart));
  }else{
    $(this).text("£" + number.toPrecision(integerPart + 2));
  }
});
```

The ones it fails on are prices like £100.0000 - I would like the prices to appear as follows - no rounding...

£0.1234

£1.10

£10.99

£100.00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a regexp to remove any trailing zeroes if the preceeding characters are the decimal period followed by another two digits:

```
$('.myClass').text(function(_, t) {
    return t.replace(/(\.\d\d)00$/, '$1');
});
```

NB: you can't use duplicate element ID's, so your `$.each` call *should* be moot.  If there really are multiple fields that this needs doing to, mark them with a class, not an ID.  The `.text` call in the code above will automatically cope with multiple elements.

**EDIT** if you really can't upgrade your jQuery:

```
$('.myClass').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var text = $this.text();
    text = text.replace(/(\.\d\d)00$/, '$1');
    $this.text(text);
});
```

Comment: hi - sorry yes there are multiple classes that this would apply to. If I use the above code however, my price is replace with the actual function code...

Comment: @user3456188 upgrade your jQuery!  This version of `.text` has existed since jQuery 1.4 (Jan '10) and you can't really expect new answers here to support a four-and-a-half year old version of a library.

Comment: doh! - getting 't.replace is not a function' now though - the price is in a span <span class="price">£1.0000</span> - thats text so it shouldn't matter right?

Comment: @user3456188 if you've upgraded jQuery and are using the first method there's a minor edit required - I forgot that the callback receives the original text in the _second_ parameter and not in the first.

Answer (score 0):

Additional to Alnitak's answer, I would highly recommend to store the prices of your store's items as integers (or maybe in your case longs), so you don't have to worry about imprecisions of double or float.

Because you have 4 decimal places the integers (or longs) can not represent pence, but 1/100 pence.

Example:

```
Price on website   |    price in database
-------------------------------------------
£0.1234            |     1234
£1.10              |    11000
£10.99             |   109900
£100.00            |  1000000
```

Comment: In JS the imprecisions will make no difference unless you're talking about trillions of pounds because JS numbers are accurate to one part in 10^17 or so.  The only important bit to remember is to use `.toFixed()` immediately before any such number is _displayed_.  In any event, calculation of VAT typically results in floating point math again.

Comment: Well, then I hope he built his shopping site entirely in JS and didn't use any other technology like PHP or Java or whatever. ;)
Using this method makes this complicated jQuery call unnecessary because you only have to put the decimal period into the string and, depending of desired accurateness, cut the last two characters.

Comment: I'm using a CMS so I cant edit the data type unfortunately but thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Sadly, I am not allowed to comment on anything other my own answers/questions yet.